# using if else with dynamic sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am new to dynamic sql and am trying to modify an existing stored proc by adding an if-else condition inside the proc. Below is the code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PUBLIC.YEAPOS2Q(IN I_PARAM1 CHARACTER(10), IN I_PARAM2 CHARACTER(8))
MODIFIES SQL DATA DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN ATOMIC    
    IF (I_PARAM2 IS NULL) THEN
        DECLARE resultSingle CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE where NAME = I_PARAM1;
    ELSE
        DECLARE resultSingle CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE where NAME = I_PARAM1 and ID = I_PARAM2;
    END IF;
END;;
```

I get the following error when I run it:

```
 HsqlException: unexpected token: DECLARE
```

Can someone please let me know what is the error here?

Thanks!

Comment: not tsql. oracle maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an `IF` in your case - just check for a null parameter in your `WHERE` clause:

```
DECLARE resultSingle CURSOR 
WITH RETURN FOR 
  SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE 
  where NAME = I_PARAM1 
    and (I_PARAM2 IS NULL OR ID = I_PARAM2);
```